# preventing deadlocks when using sockets

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am working on a server(i'm using qt as the G.U.I. framework)/client application in C++ for the first time, and I have stumbled upon a rather annoying issue.

First off, let me give some details:

```
I am on Windows 10 x64 i'm using Visual Studio as my IDE & QT for the G.U.I.
all signal/slots are used as needed are connected.
I am new to multi-threading concepts.
I am self-taught, so I don't know that much about what certain concepts are called.
```

basic outline:

```
I am currently working on the file uploader.
For the file uploader, I have two classes, one is for the thread which communicates with the client(let's call it classA) & the other is the QObject for the form(let's call it classB).


When the user closes the form 
it triggers closeEvent() in classB which sets the 'bDead' variable in classA(it uses the QMutex to make sure the other thread isn't accessing it, so I suppose it's thread-safe).
Once the client thread notices the change in classA, it finishes up it's work & sets bVerifiedDead in classB to true so they can both free themselves without worry of being accessed when destroyed.
```

for the form:

```
#include "uploadselect.h"

UploadSelect::UploadSelect(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    bClosedByUser = true;
    bVerifiedDead = false;
    bDead = NULL;
}

/*
bool UploadSelect::VerifyDeath()
{
    bool bResult;
    mutex.lock();
    bResult = bVerifiedDead;
    mutex.unlock();
    return bResult;
}
*/

void UploadSelect::Close()
{
    bClosedByUser = false;
    close();
}

void UploadSelect::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (bClosedByUser)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        *bDead = true;
        mutex.unlock();
        while (true)
        {
            mutex.lock();
            if (bVerifiedDead)
            {
                mutex.unlock();
                break;
            }
            mutex.unlock();
            Sleep(250);
        }
    }
    delete this;
}
```

uploadselect.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_uploadselect.h"

class UploadSelect : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UploadSelect(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~UploadSelect(){};
    QMutex mutex;
    bool bClosedByUser, *bDead, bVerifiedDead;
    public slots:
    void Close();
private:
    Ui::UploadSelect ui;
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
};
```

uploadselectthrd.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QThread>
#include <qsystemtrayicon.h>
#include <qtreewidget.h>

class UploadSelect;
class UploaderSelectThread : public QThread{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UploaderSelectThread(QObject* parent = 0){ bFormDead = false; };
    ~UploaderSelectThread(){};
    void run();
    bool bFormDead;
    UploadSelect* UI;
private:
    bool FormDying();
signals:
    void Close();
};
```

uploadselectthrd.cpp:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#ifndef NOMINMAX //error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'   c:\qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qdatetime.h will occur if this is not defined before windows.h/winsock2.h(winsock2 most likely includes windows.h)
#define NOMINMAX 
#endif
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <qmutex.h>
#include "FileList.h"

#include "uploadselecthrd.h"
#include "uploadselect.h"
#include "../stub/sockutils.h"

using namespace SockWrapper;


bool UploaderSelectThread::FormDying()
{
    bool bResult;
    UI->mutex.lock();
    bResult = bFormDead;
    UI->mutex.unlock();
    return bResult;
}


void UploaderSelectThread::run()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    //SocketWrapper* Client = new SocketWrapper(sSock);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6 && FormDying() == false)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        i++;
    }

    if (!FormDying())
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nbFormDead == false");
        emit Close();
    }
    else
    {
        UI->mutex.lock();
        UI->bVerifiedDead = true;
        UI->mutex.unlock();
        OutputDebugStringA("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nbFormDead == true");
    }

}
```

the way i've coded things; the sockets are synchronous so let's suppose the client's connection isn't that good and it takes ~10 seconds before the send function returns and allows the client to check the variable.

This would cause a 10 second deadlock, which sucks...

it's incomplete because the previous project got messed up(so I started a new one which i'm slowing re-coding everything into).

Possible solutions i've thought of:

```
instead of deleting the classB in closeEvent(), simply set a variable in classA in which the thread for classA will take care of it when it's finished.
```

Comment: Why not use reference counting for ClassB?

Comment: Use 'code' marker only for code, please. This is hard to read.

Comment: All the missing wrap around for the text makes it hard to read.

Comment: @MorphingDragon i've never heard of reference counting, could you provide a link to an example?

Comment: @Surt sorry, this is my first time using the editor :x.
NO_NAME sorry, i'll edit it.

Comment: [shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr) is a reference counting pointer, if it works with qt I don't know.

Comment: Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above. Can't save the modifications. Sorry.

Comment: **WHY INTRODUCING THREADS FOR NETWORK PROGRAMMING?!** Network is nonblocking by design! You can handle multiple connections within the same thread, without introducing the complexity of multithread design!

Comment: @peppe By default, Winsock's socket wrapper waits for a confirmation that the TCP packets were sent unless otherwise specified, correct? I currently have never used non-blocking sockets, so I am going to try and avoid them until I have the time to experiment with them(tomorrow is a school day so i'd have to wait a week before I get the time...)